# How to write the clear command in discord.js v12.5.3 USING ARGS[]

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a clear command for my custom discord bot and I have written some code and it works perfectly! The problem is that the command deletes 1 message less than it's told, for eg: `>clear 5` deletes 4 messages, and I know that this is happening because the command written to initiate the bulk delete itself is one message but I don't want that to happen and `args[0] + 1` doesn't seem to be working!

Here is my current code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Delete/Clear messages with a simple command",
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages to clear!");

            if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please type a real number!");

            if (args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You can't remove more than 100 messages at once!");

            if (args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You have to delete at least one message!");

            await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] }).then(messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
                message.channel.send("<a:ces_Tick:774694116042342411> **Successfully deleted " + "`" + args[0] + " messages`**")
                    .then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                    })
            });
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You don't have sufficient permissions to use this command!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you are deleting the message including your command. Eg: if its `>clear 3`, the message including your command message is cleared. So in order delete messages apart from the command message there are 3 cases.

The **first** one is to delete +1 messages like you said. If you don't want to add +1 to the number of messages, then you could follow the **second** where deleting the message as soon as the command message is sent.
Eg:

```
if(args[0]==='clear'){
    message.delete(); //deletes the message that has been sent by user.
    message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
}
```

The **third** is you can use the `before` parameter, so delete messages, before a particular message.

Eg:

```
if(args[0]==='clear'){
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0],before:message.id }).then(messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        })
}
```

The third method is the only method where the command is not deleted whereas it is deleted in the other two.
Also you don't need to use `await`, if you are using `then()` to resolve the *promise*. Learn more about [promise](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#execution-with-discord-js-code). And the *timeout parameter* will be deprecated in the upcoming version. So it's better to use `setTimeout()` method.

**EDIT:** Like Lioness100 said, you don't need to fetch messages unless you are going to use the `before` option in fetch because `bulkDelelte()` already fetches the message.

Comment: Also, unless you're using the `before` option, it's pointless to actually fetch the messages since it would take a lot of time when you could just pass then number directly into `bulkDelete`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My bad. Let me edit that out. Thanks!!